# Access Blocked: Authorization error - Expo Go React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

I've been trying to set up SignIn with google on my react native app and after implementing the code below every time I launched the web browser the Google web browser would generate the error:

`Access blocked: Authorization error. You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'
export default function LoginBox({ navigation }) {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState();

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        iosClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    })


    useEffect (() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken)
        }
    }, [response])

    const getUserData = () => {
        
    }

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>

    <Button title={accessToken ? "Get User Data": "Login"}
        onPress={accessToken ? getUserData : () => promptAsync({useProxy: 'true', showInRecents: 'true' })}
    />
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

I thought the issue might be with my redirect URI, which is https://auth.expo.io/@myusername/myslug, and my authorized JavaScript origins are https://auth.expo.io, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you install expo-dev-client in your package.json? 
Did you then run 'npx expo prebuild'?
Were you then running the custom dev-client build app with "expo run:android" or just trying to do via "Expo Go" app ("expo start"). I think have to do via the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
const EXPO_REDIRECT_PARAMS = {
    useProxy: true,
    projectNameForProxy: `@username/<YOURSCHEME>`
};

const NATIVE_REDIRECT_PARAMS = { native: '<YOURSCHEME>://' };
const REDIRECT_PARAMS =
    Constants.appOwnership === 'expo'
        ? EXPO_REDIRECT_PARAMS
        : NATIVE_REDIRECT_PARAMS;

const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId: GOOGLE_EXPO_CLIENT_ID,
        webClientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
        redirectUri: makeRedirectUri(REDIRECT_PARAMS),
    });
```

Also its important, that your scheme has the same name as your bundleidentifier in app.json.